# Can't get form to render in rails 3? Help?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I cant for the life of me work out why the form isn't rendering...

You can probably tell I am a complete beginner. I have rails 3 I think
and have managed to get other pages from this application working such
as index showing all rows on the database and also a page with
individual rows from the database.

Here's my controller

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @ad = Ad.new
  end

  def show
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @ads = Ad.find(:all)
  end
end
```

routes:

```
Mebay::Application.routes.draw do   
  match '/ads/new' => 'ads#new'
  match '/ads/create' => 'ads#create'
  match '/ads/:id' => 'ads#show'
  match '/ads' => 'ads#index'

  resources :ads  
end
```

and view:

```
<% form_for(@ad,:url=>{:action=>'create'}) do |f| %>
  <p><b>Name</b><br /><%= f.text_field :name %></p>
  <p><b>Description</b><br /><%= f.text_area :description %></p>
  <p><b>Price</b><br /><%= f.text_field :price %></p>
  <p><b>Seller</b><br /><%= f.text_field :seller_id %></p>
  <p><b>Email</b><br /><%= f.text_field :email %></p>
  <p><b>Img url</b><br /><%= f.text_field :img_url %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Create" %></p>
<% end %>
```

And here's what is rendered:

[image: rendered view with form missing]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. I spruced up your formatting a bit :-D

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the = in the tag opening that echoes the result to the view:

```
<%= form_for(@ad,:url=>{:action=>'create'}) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks Millions! How do you know when you should use an expression or a scriptlet?

Comment: are you asking when to use `<% %>` v. `<%= %>`? if so, use the latter when you want the result to be displayed in the view.